# How to print non-consecutive pages from a file, 2 pages per sheet?

Tags: linux, printing, cups, lpr

I readed a lot of information about lp and lpr linux commands. Today Im trying to print 4 non-consecutive pages from a file, 2 pages per sheet.

I tryed a lot of commands:

```
This one prints 4 sheets, 8 pages:
lp -n 1 -d C1100 -o page-ranges=1,4,5,16 -o number-up=2 /path/to/files/1.pdf
This one prints 5 sheets, 10 pages:
lp -n 1 -d C1100 -o page-set=1,4,5,16 -o number-up=2 /path/to/files/1.pdf
This one prints 4 sheets, 8 pages:
lp -P 1,4,5,16 -n 1 -d C1100 -o number-up=2 /path/to/files/1.pdf
```

Now Im lost. Could You help me?

Comment: workaround: use `pdftk` to extract just the pages you want in the order you want... then print that.

Comment: mmm And that will be fast enough to consider it? (thinking about 3 pdfs, 300mb each, 150 pags each, 50% must be cutted away....

Ok let me try and play with that command. If you want post any guide about how to cut with that command, I'll thank you.

Comment: Basically it looks like `pdftk input.pdf cat 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 output output.pdf` where the Fibonacci numbers are standing in for the page numbers (yes, you can grab a page twice—that gives you two copies of page 1).

Answer (score 0):

`pdftk` has already been mentioned by @derobert, but `ghostscript` can also be used. [This guide](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-extract-pages-pdf) details both methods.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Please review the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information regarding this. Thank you!